# Sharepoint - A feature creating a list with a workflow : Possible?

Tags: sharepoint, list, workflow

I've exported a list definition with Sharepoint Solution Generator.
This list is associated with a workflow. If I search for the name of my workflow in the generated "schema.xml" file, I find XML that looks like this :

```
<Field DisplayName="publicationWorkflow" Type="WorkflowStatus" Required="FALSE" ID="{2a2504e5-5ad0-4a9f-8bf4-15ca29e49e02}" SourceID="{4ee14f93-1f9b-4dcf-8e50-dd046dfe0905}" StaticName="publicat" Name="publicat" ColName="nvarchar1" RowOrdinal="0" Version="2" WorkflowStatusURL="_layouts/WrkStat.aspx" ReadOnly="TRUE">
        <CHOICES>
          <CHOICE>Starting</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>Failed on Start</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>In Progress</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>Error Occurred</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>Canceled</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>Completed</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>Failed on Start (retrying)</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>Error Occurred (retrying)</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE />
        </CHOICES>
      </Field>
```

Then I use a feature to regenerate the list with it's definition from SSG, but the workflow is never made, I have to go to the settings of the list and associate the workflow manually...

**So my 1st question is : Is this possible to create a list associated with a workflow using a feature?**

**And my 2nd : if yes, how?**

Comment: I have to mention that the workflow is created via the interface (it's a really basic workflow) and not with Sharepoint Designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default way to associate a Workflow to the List Definition, If you want to do you have to follow one of the following option

1. Write a Feature Receiver and write code to associate the Workflow to the List.
2. Another option is to create a content type and you can associate a workflow to that content Type using feature.

Comment: Thanks! I was about to write a feature receiver!